# Printing a image captured by the camera using the canvas

Tags: canvas, printing, imageview

HELP PLEASE, I've been stuck on this for a week now.  I'm a newb.  I've finished my simple app, but for one thing.  I need to get the captured picture to print.  Everytime I think I'm close it just crashes the app.  Any clues or help would be greatly appreciated.  The camera takes a picture and puts it in imageview, I just can't get the imageview to print. I'm using a custom print adapter and can get the text to print fine.

```
canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(textView5), center, titleBaseLine + 90,paint);
paint.setTextSize(14);

Bitmap bp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.id.camera_view);

ImageView iv= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
iv.setImageBitmap(bp);
canvas.drawBitmap(bp,0,0,paint); // this line crashes the app.
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting that crashes the app?

Comment: It looks like the exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object reference.  So I'm guessing I'm not creating the bitmap correctly.  It's a captured image from camera in imageView.  The picture does disappear if I minimize the app, so I'm assuming I'm not setting the picture correctly either.